# Eclipse CDT on Windows for Linux Development

Tags: eclipse

Anyone know how I can get eclipse/CDT in Windows to recognise all of the system calls and standard library of a linux environment? As in, show them in the right colour.. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Install MinGW or Cygwin on your windows box. Cygwin in my opinion is much closer to linux env.